# Vector Analysis & Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I'm given a positive number, a unit vector $u \in \mathbb{R} ^n $ and a sequence of vectors $ \{ b_k \} _{ k \geq 1} $  such that $|b_k - ku| \leq d $ for every $ k=1,2,...$.

This obviously implies $ |b_k| \to \infty $ . But why does this imply $\angle (u,b_k) \to 0 $ ? 
I've tried proving it using some inner-product calculations, but without any success.

In addition, why the given data implies that there must exist $i<j$ such that $|b_i| \leq \frac{\delta}{4} |b_j| $ ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $|b_k| \leq |b_k -k u| + k=d+k$, and $|b_k| \geq k-|b_k -k u|=k-d$. This gives:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{\langle u, b_k-ku\rangle}{|b_k|} = 0, \;\; \lim_{k \to \infty}  \frac{\langle u, ku\rangle}{|b_k|} = 1,$$
so it follows that
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\langle u, b_k \rangle}{|b_k|} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\langle u, b_k -ku\rangle + \langle u, ku\rangle}{|b_k|} = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks !! have you got any idea about my second question?

Comment: Fix $i$. Since $|b_j| \geq j-d$, you can choose $j$ large enough so that $|b_j| >\frac{4}{\delta} |b_i|$.

Comment: Great !!! Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

From $|b_k-k\,u|\le d$ you get that for all sufficiently large $k$
$$
k-d\le |b_k|\le k+d
$$
and
$$
k-d\le u\cdot b_k\le k+d.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{k-d}{k+d}\le\cos(\angle(u,b_k))\le\frac{k+d}{k-d}.
$$
It follows that $\cos(\angle(u,b_k))\to1$ and $\angle(u,b_k)\to0$